# Windows phone 8.1 Silverlight MessageBox shows OK button right aligned in windows 10 mobile

Tags: wpf, win-universal-app, windows-mobile, windows-phone-silverlight

Windows phone 8.1 silverlight MessageBox api shows OK button on the right side when running the same app on windows 10 mobile, however prior to this it appeared on the left, is this a behavior change from Microsoft on windows mobile 10.
Here is the msdn api link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms598690(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: API chages would have done this,how are you using MessageBox and what APIs you are using

Comment: I am deploying a windows phone 8.1 Silverlight app on windows mobile 10, I am using is it as per standard documentation from MSDN.      https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms598690(v=vs.105).aspx